# Make condition true and pass it as argument

Tags: python

I have a function where I am writing something in a file as below.

```
def func(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    lin=open(file1,"r")
    lin1=open(file,"w")
    a=lin.readline().strip('\n')
    lin1.write(a + " " + id)
    lin.close()
    lin1.close()
```

This function is calling into another function as below:

```
def afunc(arg1,arg2):
    doing stuff
    arg1.func(arg2,arg3)
```

I want a another argument should be added while writing lin1 as:

```
lin1.write(a + " " + id + " " + y/n)
```

but that y/n should come from user input. And this user input should be mention into second function `afucn()`

Example :

```
res = str(raw_input('Do you want to execute this ? (y/n)'))
```

If I press y that y should be added it lin1 and if press n that n should be added into lin1 as argument.

Comment: Just put an `if` condition before writing?

Comment: @MYGz I tried. But I want that user response in second function just above of "Doing stuff". Please let me suggest if its possible.

Comment: Can you create an [mcve]? Include full code in 1 block. Include input and output for the 2 cases that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try to show you some useful tips, by reviewing your code. I see that you are novice, so ask, if smth will stay unanswered.

```
def func(arg1,arg2,arg3):  # Make sure that you use the same names here
    # as in your actual code to avoid confusions - simplification is not a point here, 
    # especially if you are a novice
    # also, always try to choose helpful function and variable names
    lin=open(file1,"r")  # use with context manager instead (it will automatically close your file)
    lin1=open(file,"w")
    a=lin.readline().strip('\n')  # it reads only one line of you file,
    # so use for loop (like - for line in f.readlines():)
    lin1.write(a + " " + id)  # it rewrites entire file,
    # better to collect data in some python list first
    lin.close()
    lin1.close()

def afunc(arg1,arg2):
        # doing stuff  # use valid python comment syntax even in examples
        arg1.func(arg2,arg3)  # func is not a method of some python Object, 
        # so it should be called as just func(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        # when your example won't work at all
```

And your task may be implemented like

```
def fill_with_ids(id_list, input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file) as inp:
        input_lines = inp.readlines()
    output_lines = []
    for i, line in enumerate(input_lines):
        output_lines.append(line + ' ' + id_list[i])
    with open(output_file, 'w') as outp:
        outp.writelines(output_lines)


def launch(input_file, output_file):
    confirm = input('Do you want to execute this? (y/n)')
    if confirm != 'y':
        print 'Not confirmed. Execution terminated.'
        return 
    id_list = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']  # or anyhow evaluate the list
    fill_with_ids(id_list, input_file, output_file)
    print 'Processed.'


def main():
    launch('input.txt', 'output.txt')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```